# How to create a list of assets and optional input.string - Pine

Tags: pine-script

i have created an indicator with pine script - I want to publish the script for all underlying and not only for one. But this is not allowed to publish the same indicator only changed by components over and over.  How can I create a list of assets and optional input switch? How can I create a manual input of each index component using input.string or assign a string variable with ternary conditional.

Many Thanks for help

```
//@version=4
study(title="BB_Variabel", shorttitle="BB_Variabel", overlay=true,  scale=scale.none)

symbol = input(defval="SPX", title="Symbol", type=input.string, options=["SPX", "DAX", "DJI", "NDX", "AAPL", "AMZN", "GOOGL", "IBM", "GC1!", "CL1!", "DV1X", "VIX", "VXD", "VXN", "VXAPL", "VXAZN", "VXGOG", "VXIBM", "GVZ", "OVX"])

// close ist letzter Schlusskurs, close[1] ist Tag davor ..
SPX = security("SPX", "D", close[0])
VIX = security("VIX", "D", close[0])

// For debugging ..
plotchar(SPX, "SPX", "", location = location.top)
plotchar(VIX, "VIX", "", location = location.top)

upperBouhmidiBand = SPX + SPX * (VIX/100) * 0.05234239226
lowerBouhmidiBand = SPX - SPX * (VIX/100) * 0.05234239226

highTimeFrame = input("D", type=input.resolution)
sessSpec = input("0800-1715", type=input.session)

is_newbar(res, sess) =>
    t = time(res, sess)
    na(t[1]) and not na(t) or t[1] < t

newbar = is_newbar("1440", sessSpec)

var float s1 = na
var float s2 = na
if newbar
    s1 := lowerBouhmidiBand
    s2 := upperBouhmidiBand

plot(s1, linewidth = 2, style = plot.style_line, color=color.red)
plot(s2, linewidth = 2, style = plot.style_line, color=color.black)
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjo2a.png)

Comment: Do not post follow-up questions as answers. Ask a new question instead.

Comment: Please add your current code and output, showing what failed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply I edit my current code into my previous Question above. With the input option.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using the parameter `options`.
But I do not know what the maximum number assets will be possible.

```
//@version=4
study("Help (list)", overlay=true, scale=scale.left)

symbol = input(defval="SPY", title="Symbol", type=input.string, options=["SPY", "AAPL", "BAC", "TSLA", "TWTR"])

cls = security(symbol, timeframe.period, close)

plot(cls)
```

In this script, everything is the same.

```
//@version=4
study(title="Help (BB_Variabel)", shorttitle="BB_Variabel", overlay=true,  scale=scale.none)

symbol = input(defval="SPX", title="Symbol", type=input.string, options=["SPX", "DAX", "DJI", "NDX", "AAPL", "AMZN", "GOOGL", "IBM", "GC1!", "CL1!", "DV1X", "VIX", "VXD", "VXN", "VXAPL", "VXAZN", "VXGOG", "VXIBM", "GVZ", "OVX"])

// close ist letzter Schlusskurs, close[1] ist Tag davor ..
//SPX = security("SPX", "D", close[0])
SPX = security(symbol, "D", close[0])
VIX = security("VIX", "D", close[0])

// For debugging ..
plotchar(SPX, "SPX", "", location = location.top)
plotchar(VIX, "VIX", "", location = location.top)

upperBouhmidiBand = SPX + SPX * (VIX/100) * 0.05234239226
lowerBouhmidiBand = SPX - SPX * (VIX/100) * 0.05234239226

highTimeFrame = input("D", type=input.resolution)
sessSpec = input("0800-1715", type=input.session)

is_newbar(res, sess) =>
    t = time(res, sess)
    na(t[1]) and not na(t) or t[1] < t

newbar = is_newbar("1440", sessSpec)

var float s1 = na
var float s2 = na
if newbar
    s1 := lowerBouhmidiBand
    s2 := upperBouhmidiBand

plot(s1, linewidth = 2, style = plot.style_line, color=color.red)
plot(s2, linewidth = 2, style = plot.style_line, color=color.black)
```

[image]

Comment: I got it - U can put all the Symbols into one input option. But the results vary from the original one - I do not know why - its still the same calc only included the list option.

Comment: In the new script, you have fixed the timeframe "D" for the variable `SPX`, but in the original script, you use the current timeframe of the chart. Change the line to `SPX = security(symbol, timeframe.period, close[0])`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but If I do so its still not overlaying with the original one.

Comment: I have completed the answer.